# Can a cosigner take my car?

Tags: car, co-sign

Last year I purchased a car with a cosigner. I've made all payments on said car. Now that his sister inlaw and I are broken up he has taken the car. He's made no payments and has hidden the car from me. Is that legal?

Comment: Consult a lawyer.

Comment: One point of clarification, a lawyer can make the case for you in court that the other person should be removed from the title because you made all the payments, but until the title is reassigned, it may be technically legal. Check the title first.

Comment: It mostly boils down to whose name is on the title.  If a person is named on the title then they can "take" the car.  If you are also named on the title, there is nothing stopping you from taking it back.